# Closing DB in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code to insert record in Mongo by using Mongoose.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config      = require ('config');


var db = mongoose.createConnection(config.database.address, config.database.dbName);
var strCollectionName = 'category';

var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      categoryName          : {type: String, required: true , unique: true }, 
      categoryTag           : {type: String},
      categoryDescription   : {type: String},
      createDate             : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});


var createCategory = function (objCategory)
{

        var Category = db.model(strCollectionName, CategorySchema );

        var objSchema = new Category(objCategory);
        objSchema.save(function (err)
        {
            if (err)
                console.log ("Error");
            else
                console.log ("Success !!");


        });


}
```

I managed to make it work. But if i try to issue db.close () command inside save it throws error otherwise it is good. My questions is I should not have to close the connection at all ? Will Mongoose automatically takes care it ? - Im worried if the connection pool goes beyond the limit then the entire DB might crash.

Comment: What error does it throw when you call `db.close()`?  You'd typically leave `db` open until your program closes.

Answer (score 1):

To do this properly:

Define your models and tell Mongoose about them at the same time. You can do this before you create the connection.

You were previously telling Mongoose about your schema right when you wanted to use it - you only need to do this once, when you create the schema itself.

You can then open a connection for Mongoose which will work across your whole application (i.e. to use it subsequently, you just have to `require('mongoose')`):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config   = require ('config');

var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    categoryName          : {type: String, required: true , unique: true }, 
    categoryTag           : {type: String},
    categoryDescription   : {type: String},
    createDate            : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);

mongoose.connect(config.database.address, config.database.dbName);
```

If you want to manually create and manage connections you can, using .createConnection as in your example above, but unless you know what you're doing it's better to just use Mongoose's default connection.

To create a category:

```
// if you're in a different file to where you created your CategorySchema, var these:
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Category = mongoose.model("Category");

var createCategory = function (objCategory) {
    var newCategory = new Category(objCategory);
    newCategory.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.log ("Error");
        else
            console.log ("Success !!");
    });
}
```